# element is rendered without layout

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have `books/index` controller and view.
The view looks like this:

```
abcdef
123445
<?php echo $this->element('categorytree'); ?>
xyz
999
```

I have `elements/categorytree` element:

```
<?php
    function my_function() { echo '123'; } 
    echo 'element is here!';
?>
```

And when I go to books/index in my browser, the element is rendered without layout so source output is:

```
abcdef
123445
element is here!
xyz
999
```

And when I remove function declaration in element the problem disappears - the whole layout is rendered - so the problem is when I declare any php function inside element, then if this element is "fetched" by any view only this element is rendered without a layout.

This problem appeared suddenly, I don;t know why...
Before I used functions declared in element and didnt have any problem...

------------------ solved

Wow this is strange - the problem was caused by the `<!-- -->` tags after the $this->element()...

Answer (score 2):

Although you've found the solution to your problem, I'd just like to point out that defining functions in your view is a horrible practise. A better and cleaner way to do it is to create a [custom helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers), and simply use that.

A view is simply not the place to write functions or classes.